# Ofstream writing too many bytes

Tags: c++, fstream

I have some troubles when I want to write in file.
The main purpose of this program is to read all data from a exe file and after write it in another exe. 
The problem is when I write the new file, it writes too many bites. For example I read 45568 (n=45568) bytes but in the new file I have 45800 bytes and I don't understand why.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("a.exe", istream::in | ios::binary);

    std::streampos fsize = 0;
    fsize = file.tellg();

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fsize = file.tellg() - fsize;
    file.close();

    int n = fsize;
    file.open("a.exe", istream::in | ios::binary);
    std::cout << n << " " << endl;

    int z=0;
    char *p = new  char[n+1];
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        char ch;
        file.get(ch);
        p[i] = ch;
    }
    file.close();
    ofstream g;
    g.open("b.bin");
    std::cout << n;
    g.write(p, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once I have both open calls operating on the same file I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: is the same file. I forgot to change the names of file when i posted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
g.open("b.bin");
```

To be this:

```
g.open("b.bin", istream::out | ios::binary);
```

On Windows (and legacy DOS, [and many other legacy environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)), files opened in text mode get special treatment for the end of line char: `\n`.  When Windows writes a text mode file, all `\n` chars are written to file as `\r` followed by `\n`.  Similarly, file reading in text mode converts `\r\n` sequences to `\n`.  Opening files in binary mode turns off all this conversion behavior.

Also, your entire program can be simplified to:

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    in.open("a.exe", istream::in | ios::binary);
    out.open("b.bin", istream::out | ios::binary);

    while (in.rdstate() == in.goodbit)
    {
        char c;
        if (in.get(c))
        {
            out.write(&c, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianPopescu - if the answer works for you, don't forget to "Accept" the answer by giving it the green check.